# C26495 - Variable initialization warning in pure abstract class

Tags: c++, abstract-class

Here is my code:

```
class BaseBehaviour {
public:
    // Empty virtual destructor for proper cleanup
    virtual ~BaseBehaviour() {};

    // Called first and once
    virtual void Start() = 0;

    // Called every frame
    virtual void Update(float dt, bool keys[], glm::vec2 mousePos) = 0;
protected:
    GameObject* gameObject;
};
```

My question is, I shouldn't be using a variable in a pure abstract class?

I wanted to define that every class derived from `BaseBehaviour` should have a `*gameObject` variable (new to C++).
Maybe I should be using an `interface class`, or an `abstract class`?

Comment: I'm not entirely familiar with core guideline error messages but I think the guideline wants you to initialize `gameObject` like `GameObject* gameObject = nullptr;`. Right now `BaseBehaviour`' default constructor leaves the member uninitialized.

Comment: `virtual ~BaseBehaviour() {};` -> `virtual ~BaseBehaviour() = default;` There's nothing wrong with a member variable inside a class whose member functions are all pure virtual, but I suggest you provide a constructor for it. Also avoid a bare pointer for a member if you can - copying is such a headache.

Comment: @Bathsheba Indeed! MSVC code-analysis suggests: *warning C26432: If you define or delete any default operation in the type 'class BaseBehaviour', define or delete them all*

Comment: *"shouldn't I be using a variable in a pure abstract class?"* -- sure, why not? I mean, answer "why not?" in your question. Your question neglects to mention the obstacle you encountered. There is a hint in the title, but the exact warning message should be in the body.